# Enabling CORS on express-4

Tags: angularjs, node.js, web-services, cors, express-4

I have the following code in `Angular.JS`

```
$scope.resolve = function(){
    alert('In here');
    $http.get('http://cdsws.u-strasbg.fr/axis/services/Sesame?method=sesame&resultType=x&name=m3')
    .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
        alert("data"+data); 
    })
    .error(function(data,status,headers,config){
        alert("Error in Web service!"+status);
    }); 

};
```

I have added the required headers in `express`  but still not able to call the web service

```
var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Content-Length');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, Range');
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    return res.send(200);
  } else {
    return next();
  }
});
```

What else needs to be done to enable `CORS`?

I even tried using the `cors` middleware in `node Js`but no success!

```
var cors= require('cors');
var corsOptions = {
      origin: 'http://localhost:3001/'
    };
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

is there any way by which we can access the other domain URL , I can not add `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` to the other domain, the change needs to be done on the client side.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: @sideshowbarker no explicit error message, it is just not getting into success.
If I enable the `CORS plugin` in Chrome the web service responds as expected.

Comment: @Abhishek Is your chrome latest version? Also did you tried another browser?